# Android Fragment Xml using style with fatal error

Tags: android, fragment

My Android Application has a series of fragment which are the same in some style , for example,title.
I can run my app without style like this.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#4880ff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="STEP3\n最后，确定闹钟在哪些日子响起"/>
```

but when I try to use a style like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjg1B.png)
and the style tag like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC1GD.png)

Suddenly an ERROR occured.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your view has an `android:layout_height` attribute defined, either within the view or the style.

It seems to be missing from your style and if you remove it from the view the system will complain.

`android:height` is not the same as `android:layout_height`, change your style to have `android:layout_height`

Answer (score 1):

At first must use

1. `android:layout_height` instead of `android:height`
2. set `android:textColor="#ffffff"` for better approach .

Finally Your **`add_title`** looks like

```
android:layout_height="60dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Add style like below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You can define text color, background, style etc.

Answer (score 0):

do not have to do any special thing simply add this code

*android:contentDescription="@string/desc"*

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#4880ff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="STEP3\n最后，确定闹钟在哪些日子响起"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />
```

in your textview and make a string file in string xml name desc and write any thing in it. it will  work..